# Code formatting not working unless wrapped in a quote

Tags: bug, code-formatting, formatting

Never had this issue in the past, but in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41283610/819355

The only way I could get it to properly format my code snippet is by wrapping it inside a quote.

Copying the snippet to this question, and formatting as code worked ok, but when I try to edit that answer again, it doesn't.

[image]

Comment: You have to indent code by 8 spaces in enumerations. You can see it on your answer; I fixed it.

Comment: oh... I didn't relate the issue to the enumeration above... can I tell it to stop the enumeration block instead?

Comment: Yes, you can: See @deceze's answer (second half).

Comment: @CodyGray I wouldn't say it's a duplicate, the problem I experienced is pressing the `{}` button didn't format my code as it should, the reason for that is that it was confused because of the enumeration above it. IMHO the `{}` should recognize such a scenario and add 8 spaces instead of 4 to have the code properly formatted

Comment: I know what problem you experienced. The answer there covers it. I guess your point is that you want to propose a feature request whereby the toolbar button detects that your highlighted code block comes within a list. If that's the case, you forgot to tag your question [meta-tag:feature-request]. This is very much *not* a bug in the way that you presented it. The specification is quite clear on why the markdown behaves as it does.

Comment: @CodyGray i still think it's more of a bug then a feature-request, I'm not manually adding spaces, i'm clicking a button that should format my code, and it doesn't. Also, can you point me to where in the other post they mention possible clash between numbered lists and code blocks?

Comment: Under the bold heading "Code within a list"

Comment: Thanks, I searched for "enumeration" or "numbered", that's why I couldn't find it. Ok then.

Comment: Perhaps a synonym should be added to the title for ease of searching. I'll edit it in.

Answer (score 2):

It's because it's following a list and is considered part of the list item, in which case it would need to be indented even further to be recognised as code (once indented for the list item, once again for code in a list item):

```
1. Lorem ipsum

        Here is code
```

> 1. Lorem ipsum
>
>    ```
>    Here is code
>    ```

But then the code is also associated with the list item. You'll have to introduce an additional breaking element between the two; an HTML comment will do:

```
1. Lorem ipsum

<!---->

    Here is code
```

> 1. Lorem ipsum
>
> ```
> Here is code
> ```